# Could use Realm Mobile Platform instead of using other database?

Tags: database, realm, server-side, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I want start new project with Realm Mobile Platform and get a free trial of Realm Mobile Platform professional edition for testing that, and make my startup. In my project i will have some stores that sell their goods in Mall Application(Android, IOS), and my customers could search goods in all stores and see prices, and order it.

I want know about Realm Mobile Platform, will I need a database on server, or can use Realm Mobile Platform instead of a database for heavy queries and big data? 
In my research i found that Realm Mobile Platform can be used instead of RESTfull API for exchange data between Mobile client and server, but i don't know how much data can be handled by Realm Mobile Platform?

Is Realm Mobile Platform (Professional or Enterprise edition) a full database engine, or just used to exchange data and query data with other databases?

Comment: Realm **is** a database, **and** a sync engine. The `RMP - Realm Object Server` holds it all together which manages the data that is synchronized down to each user's each device in real time. You host your own ROS.

Comment: thank's @EpicPandaForce for explaining but i want to know ROS can be used instead of full database? Server-side access of ROS is enough good for query big data? or we need to other database for management of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some test and research and good comments from @Adam Fish and @Ron AB i found my answer. For using Realm Mobile Platform(RMP) i can have two strategy:

A: Using RMP for exchange data structured and store data in database engine and do other functions do with database.

B: Using RMP as database engine with NodeJS SDK or Functions (that added recently to RMP) for map/reduce mechanism to search data.

Normal strategy for developers is A because known it. For B strategy need to learning Node SDK functions and RMP APIs. For middle size of data i think B strategy is so good because have real time performance but for big data need to some coding and time to get good performance like database Engines. At the end I ❤️ like Good performance of RMP and Realm database in mobile offer to other use that.

Answer (score 0):

Realm Mobile Platform can be used to improve the performance of the application and also enables us to work offline by not always depending on the RESTful API Services. Once we synchronise the data from the server we can use the Realm Mobile to get all data. Only thing is that you need to perform timely synch with your your server data, thus improving the performance of the app by not relying on API services all the time. It is just a local database for your mobile device.

Also Realm is a proven database which has really good performance even when you have huge data on comparison to Core Data in iOS.

Telling that, of course you need to have a server with database set up to manage all your data on the server which will be accessed by multiple devices accessing your server.

Comment: Hi @Ron Ab thank's for sharing your experience. I have some test with RMP and see amazing performance of data exchange but i want to know server-side data access is just for small queries or can handle big queries? Because i like this structure of so many small databases that can be searchable.

Comment: Server side data queries can be anything - big or small. That is why we just give queries to be processed using a server. A good server will be able to process any queries and handle good traffic using various techniques like load-balancers or so on. Only thing is that you need to design the server side.

Comment: that's good, what is better database or RMP? In your answer you say database is better and i think to be correct. I need to know what is roadmap and goal of RMP? Be a fully functional database or just make a light and fast way to exchange data?

Comment: RMP can be your backend completely or act as middleware. It is designed not to be too picky and fit with the architecture that suits you best. That is why we offer a data connector API to sync to other databases. From a pure backend perspective, you can do "big queries" via a map/reduce mechanism. If your data is in lots of different Realms, you could loop over them, apply a mapping function, adding results into another Realm, then reduce those results further. We would like to formalize this in the future, but can be done manually with the Node SDK today.